# EventHandler to get HDMI connectivity in windows application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, hdmi

I am looking for event handler to get the information when HDMI is connected or disconnected using c#/WPF  like how myNetworkAvailabilityChangeHandler is used to detect when internet gots disconnected or connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct answer to this but you can use the **SystemEvents** to achieve this.

Code in C# :

```
main()
{
SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new 
EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged); 
}       
private void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int HDMI_Monitors = 0;
        ManagementClass mClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\localhost\ROOT\WMI:WmiMonitorConnectionParams");
        foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mClass.GetInstances())
        {
            var ss = mObject["VideoOutputTechnology"];
            if(ss.ToString().StartsWith("5"))
            {
                int HDMIport = Convert.ToInt32(ss);
                if (HDMIport == 5)
                {
                    HDMI_Monitors += 1;
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

You can use the model class to keep on updating the HDMI status.
So every time your HDMI will connect or disconnect **SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged** will trigger and then it will check the HDMI connection.